# Angular making http post not working

Tags: angular, http, http-post, http-get

I'm trying to make an http post request in Angular and can't figure out why its not working.

```
getTripEstimate(event){
    let authUsername:string = '*****';
    let authPassword:string = '*****';
    let headers = new Headers();
    let params = {
      "grant_type": "*****",
      "scope": "*****",
      "username": "*****",
      "password": "*****"
    };
    let body = JSON.stringify(params)
    console.log("body: "+body)
    this.http.post("http://localhost:8000/auth/oauth/token",{
        headers: headers,
        body: body
    }).toPromise().then(res => console.log(res.json)).catch(res => console.log("Error"))
  }
```

I have commented out the passwords and username but i'm getting a 401 error and can't figure out why if the credentials i'm using are correct because they worked through postman. Maybe i'm making the POST request incorrectly?

Comment: You can try to use Postman to see if you are able to create a working http post request outside Angular. Then try to replicate it in Angular and see if the request is conform with Chrome network dev tools.

Comment: I did do that. and tried replicating in Angular but i guess i'm not doing it correctly from my code pasted above? ^

Comment: It should be `new HttpHeaders()`

Comment: I added that import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'; and changed from new Headers() to new HttpHeaders() but it still didn't work

Comment: The constructor is `httpClient.post(url, body, options)` with options being your header

Answer (score 0):

Try this to make a post request

```
     getTripEstimate(event){
            this.http.post("http://localhost:8000/auth/oauth/token",{
      **use what ever params you want to send**
              "username": "*****",
              "password": "*****"
            },
              { headers: headers})
              .subscribe(response => {
               console.log(response);
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not building your request properly:

The correct constructor for the HttpClient is `httpClient.post(url, body, options)`

```
this.http.post(
  "http://localhost:8000/auth/oauth/token",
  body,
  headers: headers
).subscribe(res => { console.log(res); }, error => console.log(error))
```

Comment: This didn't give me an error but how to i get the response?

Comment: I updated to show how to console log the response. The `post()` function returns an observable. You have to subscribe to an observable to start it.

Comment: Ploppy thank you for that but this that still give me a 401 error.  Failed to load http://localhost:8000/auth/oauth/token: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401.

Comment: Then you have to check the header and the body of the request in chrome network dev tools to make sure the request has all the needed parameters.

Comment: also i had to do {headers:headers} because just simply writing headers: headers because its expecting 2-3 arguments but writing it that way is 4 args so i had to do {headers: headers} but still getting the error i mentioned above.